# Is it possible to set the font size for all fonts in a Swift iOS app?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, font-size

In order for user friendly, i wish to let user customise the font size of entire app in setting page.

Rather than find out every single font and style it, is there any solution to set entire font's size one shot?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special, just don't hardcode fonts in your app. Instead use `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle:)` In iOS settings users can change their preferred font size that way your app can automatically adapt to it

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set ALL text to be the same size, as that would not look good or be legible, and it goes against [Apple's Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) for typography.

This would be the opposite of "user friendly". You need some [visual weight/hierarchy](https://www.canva.com/learn/typeface-fonts/) to distinguish sections of content and their importance, and focus the user's attention. If everything's the same size, it's hard to find what they need.

So, with this in mind, you couldn't just have 1 setting for them - you'd need to have separate settings for every type of text in your app. [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/) has already built this functionality for you at the OS level.

This is called "[Dynamic Type](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-dynamic-type-to-resize-your-apps-text)," which lets you [set text sizes](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dynamic-types-ios-tutorial-ios11) based on the purpose of a particular bit of type - headlines, subheads, titles, body text, captions, etc. You don't have to manually find/change fonts.

For example:

```
let headlineFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)
let subheadFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.subheadline)
```

This isn't an in-app setting as you asked about, but is set in the iOS System Settings. Whatever default font size the user selects in Settings will be reflected in your app. This also requires that you've considered what sort of text each element is. Is it a headline, a label, a caption, etc.